# how to apply jquery functions to ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm using the tooltipster plugin to create tooltips.
some of the content where i want to apply the plugin  is loaded via AJAX when the page opens.

i tried using

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
$('.tip1').tooltipster();
});
```

but it seems to  apply the function only on the main page contents, not on the ajax loaded contents.

this DOES work :

```
$(document).on('ready ajaxComplete', function() {
$('.tip1').tooltipster();
});
```

but it seems to cause errors if the content is re-loaded again via AJAX.
i see lots of this warning in the console :

> Tooltipster: one or more tooltips are already attached to this element: ignoring. Use the "multiple" option to attach more tooltips

whats the best way of getting this to work?

EDIT : 
the external content is loaded like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
url = "source_url.php";
target= ".holder";
$(target).load(url);
});
</script>
<div class="holder"></div>
```

Comment: Please, add the code of how you load and append content loaded by ajax

Comment: They describe how to achieve this in http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#functionBeforeExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  url = "source_url.php";
  target= ".holder";
  $(target).load(url, function() { $('.tip1', $(this)).tooltipster(); });
});
```

Comment: i tried this but unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything...  the tooltip isn't being applied to the ajax loaded content...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the correct way to apply the plugin on content loaded via AJAX would be to add a callback function to your AJAX call. I don't know how you append your content loaded via AJAX but for example, if you look at the jQuery doc for $.load, you can add a 'complete' parameter that should be a function. This function will be called when the ajax request completes. It would look something like this :

```
$(element).load('content.html', function() {
    $('.tip1').tooltipster();
});
```

Now, I've never used Tooltipster but it says it's already attached, there's for sure a method to detach it from the content and reattach again. A quick look at it's doc there's a destroy method

```
$(...).tooltipster('destroy');
```

That means you could call the destroy method before reapplying the plugin to your content. Using the same ajax code with the callback function, it would give you something like this :

```
$(element).load('content.html', function() {
    $('.tip1').tooltipster('destroy').tooltipster();
});
```

I didn't actually test this code but this should help you.

Comment: nice idea, but now i get this error "You called Tooltipster's "destroy" method on an uninitialized element"... i tried moving the original call to tooltipster to the head of the page (originally in the bottom) but get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative you can use `DOMNodeInserted` event but this event will be removed and not sure about cross browser support.

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.tip1', function(e) {
  $(e.target).tooltipster();
});
```